# Удаление символов input mask jquery

Tags: html, jquery, input

Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалять символы из input.
Сейчас удаляется только последний символ.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#phone").inputmask({
    "mask": "+38 (999) 999-99-99"
  });
});
function del_ch() {
  var type = $("#phone").val();
  $("#phone").val(type.substring(0, type.length - 1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone">
<input type="button" value="DEL" onclick="del_ch();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам надо полностью удалить все введённые значения, то можно так:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#phone").inputmask({
    "mask": "+38 (999) 999-99-99"
  });
});
function del_ch() {
  var type = $("#phone").val();
  $("#phone").val("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone">
<input type="button" value="DEL" onclick="del_ch();">
```

Если по одной последней цифре - то надо модифицировать данные, так как стоит маска и вместо последней цифры Вы получаете _
Регулярные выражения расписал отдельно с комментарием, чтобы было понятнее. (Можно объединить)

```js
$(function() {
    $("#phone").inputmask({
        "mask": "+38 (999) 999-99-99"
    });
});
function del_ch() {
    var type = $("#phone").val();
    last = type.substr(-1); //пробовал вот так
    last = type.slice(-1); //и вот так
    type = type.replace(/_/g, ""); // Удаляем нижнее подчёркивание
    type = type.replace(/-/g, ""); // Удаляем тире
    type = type.replace(/[()]/g, ""); // Удаляем скобки
    type = type.replace(/[ ]/g, ""); // Удаляем пробелы
    $("#phone").val(type.substring(0, type.length - 1));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone">
<input type="button" value="DEL" onclick="del_ch();">
```